# Oracle INSTR exact match

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, substring

i have the following query

```
SQL> select * from RTECS_ABBREV ra
  2  where instr(trim('100 mmol/plate (-S9)'), ra.abbrev) > 0;

ABBREV                         DEFINITION
------------------------------ --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
mmo                            Mutation in Micro-organism
mmol                           millimole
mol                            mole
S                              second

SQL>
```

I want get the following result

```
SQL> select * from RTECS_ABBREV ra
  2  where instr(trim('100 mmol/plate (-S9)'), ra.abbrev) > 0;

ABBREV                         DEFINITION
------------------------------ --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
mmol                           millimole
S                              second

SQL>
```

since "mmo" and "mol" are part of "mmol" word

more ....

See I have the following data:

```
with abbr as
(
      select 'mmo' as abbrev from dual union 
      select 'mmol' as abbrev from dual union
      select 'mol' as abbrev from dual union
      select 'ug' as abbrev from dual union
      select 'mg' as abbrev from dual union
      select 'ppm' as abbrev from dual union
      select 'nmol' as abbrev from dual union
      select 'nm' as abbrev from dual union
      select 'ol' as abbrev from dual union
      select 'S' as abbrev from dual

),
main_data  as
(
select '24231' as id_, '10 ug/plate (-S9)' as data_ from dual union 
select '24232' as id_, '1 pph' as data_ from dual union 
select '24233' as id_, '100 mmol/plate (-S9)' as data_ from dual union 
select '24234' as id_, '100 mmol/plate (-S9)' as data_ from dual union 
select '24235' as id_, '1 pph' as data_ from dual union 
select '24236' as id_, '19300 nmol/L (-S9)' as data_ from dual union 
select '24237' as id_, '800 mg/L' as data_ from dual union 
select '24238' as id_, '600 ppm/2H-C (-S9)' as data_ from dual union 
select '24239' as id_, '500 mg/L (-S9)' as data_ from dual union 
select '24240' as id_, '2000 ppm (-S9)' as data_ from dual union 
select '24241' as id_, '100 mmol/plate (-S9)' as data_ from dual union 
select '24242' as id_, '1 pph (-S9)' as data_ from dual union 
select '24243' as id_, 'ihl 2700 ppm' as data_ from dual union 
select '24244' as id_, 'par 10 mmol/L' as data_ from dual union 
select '24245' as id_, 'mul 1 pph/8H-C' as data_ from dual                          
)
select * from main_data
```

I need replace in "main_data.data_" any occurrence of matching words in "abbr.abbrev" with another string (for example: "test").

So for example for "100 mmol/plate (-S9)" I need to have:

```
100 test/plate (-test9) but not,

100 testl/plate (-test9) or 100 testol/plate (-test9)
```

so the rule seems to be, replace whole word match in "abbr.abbrev" and if string is between () replace any matching characters

Comment: I don't understand.  "mmo" is in the string.  Why wouldn't it be returned?  Please explain the rules that you are using.

Comment: Can you please explain the rules and post the table and insert statements. It is unclear what you are asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your example data, I think you want something like the following:

```
SELECT * FROM main_data INNER JOIN abbr
    ON REGEXP_LIKE(main_data.data_, '(^|\W)' || abbr.abbrev || '(\W|$)');
```

I use the regular expression above because Oracle regular expressions don't support word boundaries. In the first group I am checking for the start of a string or a "non-word" character (neither alphanumeric nor an underscore `_`). In the latter (ending) group I am checking for the end of a string or a non-word character.

It strikes me that checking for the beginning of a string (anchor `^`) isn't really necessary if you're always going to have some measure of the given unit.

If you're going to do a replace, you'll want to use `REGEXP_REPLACE()` with the above regular expression instead of merely using `REGEXP_LIKE()`.